# Which Windows apps use the "DNS client" service?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, windows-services

I'm thinking of Windows 10/11.

Which Windows 10 apps use the "DNS client" service?
I guess Windows apps like browsers, mail clients, etc have their own DNS clients (also called "stub resolvers") and therefore bypass Windows DNS client.  They all use the DNS servers set up by the Operating System (in the properties for the network adapter).

Also: am I right that the Windows DNS cache that you can check with `ipconfig /displaydns` only stores DNS records resolved by the Windows DNS client? So that each Windows app will use their own caches?

Any clarification much appreciated.

Comment: Please limit your question to one (main) question, makes it much easier to answer.

Comment: `I guess Windows apps like browsers, mail clients, etc have their own DNS clients` - this is not true for all operating systems, be it modern or old. Since the original days of ARPANET it is the duty of the OS to resolve DNS for applicatoins. Because of this no modern application does DNS resolution on their own because the OS have resolution logic that users expect to work eg. expecting the DHCP to configure DNS servers, expecting the hosts file to work, expecting DNS server you configure in network control panel to work, expecting DNS cache to work etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I guess Windows apps like browsers, mail clients, etc have their own DNS clients (also called "stub resolvers") and therefore bypass Windows DNS client

No, they very rarely do. It's mostly only special purpose apps (and some, but certainly not all, web browsers) that tend to have their own stub resolvers. The majority of programs that only need to resolve a hostname to an address will use the OS resolver instead.

(Typically programs that need to resolve non-address record types such as TXT are likely to have their own stub resolver, like how OpenSSH uses libldns to look up SSHFP records, while still using the OS resolver for hostnames.)

In general, if a program can successfully use *non-DNS* names (such as mDNS foo.local) then it is very likely that it uses the OS resolver.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the first point mentioned above is not Windows-specific. The same is generally true on macOS and Linux as well (though on Linux it’s much easier to force everything to use a shared cache, because you can trivially run a local caching resolver and trick everything into using that as their sole DNS server).

Comment: Sole _DNS_ server, yes, but the system resolver often handles more than just DNS – you'd still need a special local resolver that implements its own /etc/hosts lookup, its own mDNS (a bit like how systemd-resolved works), or ideally all of the nsswitch hostname modules.

Comment: @user1686 That's completely covered by the *C library*, not DNS resolver. An application just calls `getaddrinfo` and the rest is handled by libc. For glibc, a module called "Name Service Switch" reads `nsswitch.conf` and defers hostname resolution to listed modules, including but not limited to `file` (the hosts file) and `mdns`,

Comment: @iBug: The point, though, is that programs which use their own resolver library (whether libresolv or libldns or something else) – the ones being discussed here – do not use getaddrinfo(); they craft their own DNS query packets and Austin's "trick everything" will not actually trick them into using getaddrinfo().

Comment: @user1686 My experience tells that only DNS utilities (`dig`, `nslookup` etc.) implement their own resolver. All other software with network capabilities just go for `getaddrinfo`.

Comment: @iBug: It's not that uncommon; I've seen at least three programs that used `c-ares` alone just because they needed asynchronous lookup and libc interfaces couldn't provide that easily; NodeJS might be the most common one. (Aside from that, programs that need DNS records other than A/AAAA (e.g. ssh which needs SSHFP records, SMTP servers which need MX records, libkrb5 which needs SRV/URI records) will have no choice but to use their own resolver, as that's not something they _could_ get via getaddrinfo() at all – although my initial comment doesn't quite apply to that situation anyway.)

Answer (score 9):

> Which Windows 10 apps use the "DNS client" service?

In layman's terms: all and none, the DNS clients is integrated into the TCP/IP stack (within the application layer).

In principle all apps that try to access an URL via DNS will "involve" the DNS client (although indirectly by sending a request to resolve the OS via the TCP/IP stack), since it's main purpose is to cache DNS names. However if you deactivate it DNS resolution will still work but the DNS name will be resolved via a DNS server which takes more time then just looking up the cache.

So yes, you are correct, it will be browsers, email clients etc. to use the "DNS client" service

> I guess Windows apps like browsers, mail clients, etc have their own DNS clients (also called "stub resolvers") and therefore bypass Windows DNS client.

No, you are mixing up DNS cache and DNS resolvers. Most apps use the OS (TCP/IP stack) to resolve a DNS name and therefore they (indirectly) use the DNS client. **But** if they have their own cache and the DNS name happens to be stored in their cache no resolvment via the OS is needed therefore the Windows DNS client gets bypassed.

> Also: am I right that the Windows DNS cache that you can check with ipconfig /displaydns only stores DNS records resolved by the Windows DNS client?

Yes `ipconfig /displaydns` only shows you the cache from the DNS client.

> So that each Windows app will use their own caches?

No, not all apps have their own DNS cache, so not all of the can use their own cache, but for the once which do, yes.

Note: there is a second purpose which is to register your computer's DNS name with the domain server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still confused.  If I understood you correctly: Chrome (for example) will use the Windows DNS client service unless you disable it.  Now: I checked the DNS cache with the command "ipconfig /displaydns" and I could not find any of the URLs I had browsed.  So if what you say is true: then Chrome is using Windows DNS cache service but the resolved names are stored in Chrome's own DNS cache, not in Windows cache, right? If this is so, what apps are storing their DNS queries in the Windows DNS cache?

Comment: @Antonio23249 in layman's terms: the browser uses its own DNS cache first, then the "Windows DNS cache", and then it tries to resolve it through the DNS server... see here (note, I just looked over it very briefly) https://think.unblog.ch/en/how-to-check-and-query-dns-caching/

Comment: @Antonio23249 your understanding of DNS is lightly "off". Mo application uses the Windows DNS cache to store "it's" DNS queries. If it doesn't have an DNS adress in it's own cache (or doesn't have a cache) it asks the opperating system to resolve the DNS name. So Windows DNS cache belongs to the OS not a particular app. I hope that makes it clearer. (all in layman's terms of course)

Comment: Albin, thanks for your patience.  I read that article and it's quite clear.  The test I did is that I first cleared Chrome's DNS cache and then browsed some websites.  If Chrome is using the Windows DNS client service, then the URLs should appear with ipconfig /displaydns, right?.  Unless the name resolutions are instead stored only in Chrome's own DNS cache.

Comment: @Antonio23249 essentially correct

Comment: I believe Chrome and Firefox use the aptly named [DoH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS) protocol, because lots of providers now manipulate DNS for commercial or legal reasons, and this mitigates that for non-expert users.

Comment: @SimonRichter not sure if I understood your comment correctly. Yes, DNS names can be securely resolved via https, but to my knowledge that doesn't have any effect on the DNS cache

Comment: @Albin, the browsers skip the normal resolver, that would explain why hostnames from browsed URLs don't show up in the resolver cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, clarified now.